# Exception calling "CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups" with 3 arguments: Access denied

Tags: powershell, permissions, 2016, create-groups

Goal: Use PowerShell to create the default permissions groups (Owners, Visitors, Members) after site collection being created with PowerShell.

I Logged into the Application server with a farm admin account, running PowerShell as admin:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteCollectionUrl    
$web.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups("DOMAIN\sitecollectionadmin", "", "")
```

I am getting below result:

```
Exception calling "CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups" with "3" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

Is there any specific permission I need to grant the account that I am using to run PowerShell so I don't get the Access denied error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a few things:

1. User isn't a local administrator on the server
2. User isn't a farm admin
3. (Most likely) user doesn't have full control on the Web App policy (this would generally be preferred for ease of administration versus assigning the account as a Site Collection Admin)

Comment: The user that is being used to log into the App Server and run PS was already a local admin on the server (1) and a farm admin (2). I added the account with Full Control on the Web App policy in Central Admin (3) and now when I run CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups I get the error: `Exception calling "CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups" with "3" argument(s): "User cannot be found." ` Is this referring to the user "DOMAIN\sitecollectionadmin" that I want to add in the owners group not being found in the site collection permissions group? It is already a site collection admin.

Comment: Since you're on 2016, you should be supplying the claims value for the account, e.g. `i:0#.w|domain\username`.

Comment: When I go into Policy for Web Application on Central Admin, I do see User Name = i:0#.w|domain\username. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: That'd be correct. That is the Windows Claims format of the username which is what that method is expecting in your case.

Comment: Error resolved by modifying to `$web.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups("", "", "")` which successfully created the default groups Visitors, Members and Owners in the site, but added the account that I was using to run the PS in the Owner's group. Just deleted it manually by going to Site Settings>People and Groups>Owners group